# SpiderMonkey js shell won't bump bytecode?

Tags: javascript, shell, bytecode, spidermonkey

I downloaded the nightly [js-shell for mac](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla-central/jsshell-mac.zip) from [mozilla's ftp site](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/latest-mozilla-central/).

If I run:

```
~/Downloads/jsshell-mac/js -D --execute="var a = '100'"
```

I assume I would get bytecode output. Instead, I get nothing.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like this mentioned nowhere, but for this option to work you will need a debug build.
For example [this build](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/2012-08-15-mozilla-beta-debug/jsshell-mac.zip) should work, or you can get the source and do the [building](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Build_Documentation) yourself.

Comment: Yep, that was it! I find it ridiculous that this is not mentioned once across the entire mozilla wiki. Thank you so much!